# Commit errors after importing OpenCV into Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, opencv, github, commit

I've tried nearly every guide to importing OpenCV into Android Studio, but I still get thousands of compile errors when I commit my project (to a new repo) and the code analysis is run, as shown below:

[image: errors]

I am importing OpenCV 4.3.0 (Android SDK) and following the steps from another post:

[image: steps]

I have been trying this in a brand new project and have also attempted matching build.gradle values, such as compileSdkVersion. What am I missing? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout the `build.gradle` for OpenCVLibrary430. Since you are using it as a library, sometimes it defined as application.

```
//apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
```

Another check could be your `settings.gradle` file. `include` the right file there after changes like `include ':openCVLibrary430'`

Lastly, rather than clean project, try "File" -> "Invalidate Caches...", and select "Invalidate and Restart" option.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. Unfortunately I'm still getting the same errors. It was already defined as a library and also included in settings.gradle. So frustrating...